# Same Number, different area code

Tags: contacts

I know there was a similar question asked earlier
[Same phone number with different code problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11618/same-phone-number-with-different-code-problem#)
But none of the answers are of any help and it is now 4 years and several versions later. There was even a bug report opened on the issue that is now marked as "obsolete" but I am still having the issue.  
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18684

Phone: Samsung galaxy s4 i9505  
Version: 5.0.1 Lollipop 
Issue: two different contacts with the same number but different area code 
eg 
Larry: (411) 123-4567 
Sarah: (909) 123-4567 
When a phone call comes in from either number, Larry's contact info (picture, name) is displayed in caller Id.

Any suggestions?